# How to exclude certain matches in a Regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to match strings that end with `bar`, for example: `foobar` or `bar`. Such regexp could be: `/^.*bar$/`.

I would also like to exclude strings with the letter `u` prefixed to `bar`, for instance, these strings should not match the regular expression: `ubar` or `fooubar`. I tried `/^.*[^u]?bar$/`, but it doesn't work. How could we fix this?

Comment: Which language or tool are you using?

Comment: [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Comment: Please always include this in any regex question, because regex engine implementations can differ greatly.

Comment: Oh, yes I didn't think. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply wrap the whole prefix in parentheses

```
^(.*[^u])?bar$
```

By doing this you only allow further preceding characters, if there was at least one non-`u` character before `bar`.

Alternatively, if your regex engine supports [negative lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you could do this:

```
^.*(?<!u)bar$
```

When this regex reaches the position before `bar` it looks at the character left of it and tries to match a `u`. If that is not possible, the match continues. If the `u` was found the lookbehind will make the pattern fail. This works both if there is a non-`u` character and if it's the beginning of the string.

As sawa pointed out in a comment, you don't even need the `^.*` if you just want to check whether a string ends in `bar`:

```
(?<!u)bar$
```

Of course, if you want to include the whole string in the match for some reason (replacement or matching lines using multiline mode) then the `^.*` is necessary. Note that in the first regex you cannot leave it out. However you could change it to

```
([^u]|^)bar$
```

Which would also avoid matching the whole string.

Comment: @sawa yep that is true. I just wasn't sure about the usecase. For instance, if the OP is using the original pattern with multiline mode to find lines that end in `bar`, it might be desirable to capture the whole line in the match.

Answer (score 1):

Group everything preceding the `?` in `()`. This has the effect of saying *"the whole optional structure preceding `bar`, if present, must not end in `u`"*.

For example in JavaScript:

```
/^(.*[^u])?bar$/.test("foobar");
// true

/^(.*[^u])?bar$/.test("fooubar");
// false

/^(.*[^u])?bar$/.test("bar");
// true

/^(.*[^u])?bar$/.test("ubar");
// false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookbehind:

```
def match_bar? string
  string =~ /(?<!u)bar\z/
end

%w{foobar ubar fooubar}.each do |example|
  puts "#{example} does #{match_bar?(example) ? '' : 'not'} match the regex."
end
```

Output:

```
foobar does  match the regex.
ubar does not match the regex.
fooubar does not match the regex.
```

Comment: Fixed.  I find \z or \Z to be more useful than $ in most cases.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste. I find them less readable, so I prefer to use `$` when I know I'm not using multiline mode anyway.